# Symfony 3.4 inject service inside another fail

Tags: symfony

I am doing a service in Symfony and I need to inject my mail service. The mail service depends on a parameter:

```
app.email:
        class: AppBundle\Services\EmailNotificationService
        autowire: false
        public: true
        arguments:
        - '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
        - '@swiftmailer.mailer'
        - '@templating.engine.twig'
        - '%mailer_user%'
        - '@logger'
```

It works to inject it into one service:

```
app.booking:
        class: AppBundle\Services\BookingService
        autowire: false
        public: true
        arguments:
        - '@doctrine'
        - '@pay.pay'
        - '@app.calendar'
        - '@app.email'
        - '@app.push'
```

but when I include it in another:

```
services:
    app.servicios_extras:
        class: AppBundle\Services\ServiciosExtrasService
        autowire: false
        public: true
        arguments:
            - '@app.email'
...

class ServiciosExtrasService
{
    private $mailer;

    public function __construct(EmailNotificationService $mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }
```

it gives me the error:

```
Cannot autowire service "AppBundle\Services\EmailNotificationService": argument "$mailerUser" of method "__construct()" has no type-hint, you should configure its value explicitly.
```

I'm missing something?

**UPDATE**

app/config/services.yml:

```
_defaults:
        # automatically injects dependencies in your services
        autowire: true
        # automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        autoconfigure: true
        # this means you cannot fetch services directly from the container via $container->get()
        # if you need to do this, you can override this setting on individual services
        public: false
```

Comment: is your booking service actually getting used? because this problem may only occur, when it is (also, it appears the servicios extras is maybe just defined earlier, and the  booking service would throw the same error). if you don't mind me asking, why do you set `autowire: false` everywhere?

Comment: Please update your question with the _defaults section of your services.yml file.  Is your ExtrasService defined in the same service file as app.email?  I suspect that you have autowire enabled on a global level which means that the container is trying to make two EmailNotificationService's.  One based on your configuration and one based on autowire.  Adding AppBundle\Services to the excluded directories might work around the problem.

Comment: @Cerad yes, you're right i have autowire enabled on a global level, and yes, ExtraService is defined in the same service file as app.email. I exclude services folder in config (exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests,Services}') and now is working!

Comment: @Cerad why  the container is trying to make two EmailNotificationService's. One based on your configuration and one based on autowire ? (I am new to symfony and I am supporting a system made.)

Comment: The Symfony container has moved away from explicitly naming services with things like like app.email.  Instead, the class name (AppBundle\Services\EmailNotificationService) is preferred.  So autowire finds all classes under src, looks in container to see if a service has been defined with the same class name and, if none is found, creates a new service.  Autowire does not link app.email with your email class.  Unless you are supporting a legacy project then it might be best to do away with app.* service names.

Comment: And, as a bonus, by going with class names you can eliminate all the service configuration except for a [bind](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-local-service-binding) under the _default section.  But it looks like you do have a legacy project in which case you should probably turn off autowire under _default just to preserve your own sanity.

Comment: @Cerad thank you very much for your help, if you write the answer I select it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't normally answer these sorts of questions because there are a number of similar questions with the same answer.  But I could not find one that could be considered to be a duplicate.

The short answer is to add the Services directory to the list of excluded directories:

```
#app/config/services.yml
    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests,Services}'
```

Doing so prevents autowire from trying to create a service with an id of AppBundle\Services\EmailNotificationService and then failing because $emailUser is a string.

The Symfony container has moved away from explicitly naming services with things like app.email. Instead, the class name (AppBundle\Services\EmailNotificationService) is preferred. So autowire finds all classes under src, looks in container to see if a service has been defined with the same class name and, if none is found, creates a new service. Autowire does not link app.email with your email class. Unless you are supporting a legacy project then it might be best to do away with app.* service names.

And, as a bonus, by going with class names you can eliminate all the service configuration except for a bind under the _default section. But it looks like you do have a legacy project in which case you should probably turn off autowire under _default just to preserve your own sanity.